# How can I check in Apex if a batch is scheduled?

Tags: batch-file, salesforce, apex, schedule

I am calling a batch through a system.scheduleBatch(BatchableClass(query), 'Job Name', MinutesToExecute) method. How can I check if the batch job *Job Name* is already scheduled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

You would want to do something like:

```
CronTrigger ct = 
[SELECT TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :jobID AND NextFireTime > :DateTime.Now()];
```

I didn't check that exact syntax, but I verified this works in the dev console:

```
SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger where NextFireTime > today
```